# How to avoid Navigation of folders through URL manipulation

Tags: php, url, directory, root

Please i need your help with my website (testing stage).
I have a file system of this nature...

```
     www (root)  
  {

           school { //main project folder

                  images //images folder

                  uploads //user uploads folder 

                  JavaScripts //JS folder

                  CSS // css folder

                 includes //includes folder

             index.php

            contactus.php

            aboutus.php

            register.php

           } //main project folder
  } //www folder
```

how can i prevent users from browsing through my folder system when they do somrthing like these:

```
 http://127.0.0.1/school/css
 http://127.0.0.1/school/images
 http://127.0.0.1/school/includes
 http://127.0.0.1/school/uploads
 http://127.0.0.1/school/javascripts
```

Thnaks for your help....

Comment: Usually direct directory listing is not allowed by default. What are you seeing when you try to access the folders directly?

Comment: @truth I run Apache (WAMP). When i view those folders through the URL i see Index of the folders i.e all the scripts or all the images or the CSS files or the Javascripts...all the contents of the folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[See the following article on how to disable direct directory browsing](http://www.techiecorner.com/106/how-to-disable-directory-browsing-using-htaccess-apache-web-server/)**

Specifically, search for `Options Indexes` in your .htaccess file. If one does not exist, add the following line to your .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Directory browsing should not be available.

More methods are available at the article above.

Answer (score 2):

You could also put an empty php or html file called index.php or index.html in every folder. 
The users will be unable to browse those directories.

Answer (score 0):

Create an .htaccess file to the directory you don't want to be navigated via url input..

and inside the file, put this line:

```
Deny from all
```

that's all.. enjoy..

and for security purposes use this lines instead:

```
Options -Indexes
```